# Gitlab Webhook cant launch Jenkins job (via Build Token Root Plugin)

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

I want to begin Jenkins build automatically after commit to GitLab (git panel).

So I've setup this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin and configured it:

[image]

Then I`ve added webhook to GitLab:

[image]

Now I can launch Jenkins task via http-request (from browser for example) but w/o success from Gitlab (via button "Test Hook"). Why?

Is webhook of GitLab not the same as http-request?

I can autolaunch of this Jenkins job via https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gitlab+Hook+Plugin but cant, due to restrictions of standard git plugin of Jenkins.

Comment: Looks that this is problem with authorization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that you've configured the Build Token Root Plugin, but your webhook URL ends with `/build?token=test`.

Though if you read the plugin documentation, it says:

> This plugin offers an alternate URI pattern which is not subject to the usual overall or job read permissions. Just ping `buildByToken/build?job=NAME&token=SECRET`.

The URL you're using won't work in a Jenkins setup with authentication — hence why the Build Token Root Plugin exists — you need to use that plugin's URL pattern.

i.e. in your case it should be something like:
`https://jenkins.example.com/buildByToken/build?job=Config+Generator+Launch+UAT+PP+PROD&token=test`

It seems a bit weird to me that you have two levels of `/job/` in the job name, but maybe you're using the folders plugin or something?  So maybe the `job` parameter will have to be `Configuration+Delivery/job/Config+Generator+Launch+UAT+PP+PROD` or so.

In any case, you can play around by calling those URLs directly from your browser, rather than having to change the GitLab hook URL and hitting <kbd>Test Hook</kbd> every time.

Comment: thank you. It was my fault. I`ve installed "Build Token Root Plugin" but continue to use default build trigger.